# Google Play Game Services - Listener null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I am still fairly new to Android and I am trying to implement Achievements inside my app. I basically want to replicate the achievements implemented in the "Type-a-Number Challenge" sample app given on the Google play developer site [here](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/).

I have a first activity that contains the methods and classes to handle the achievements, and a second activity where I have the variables that would be forwarded to the first activity for "processing". I copied the code that I believed was necessary for doing this,  but I am always getting a null pointer exception when calling the listener inside the second class.

Here is my listener in the second activity:

```
public interface Listener {
    public void onEnteredScore(int score);
}

Listener mListener = null;

public void setListener(Listener l) {
    mListener = l;
}
```

The null pointer exception is flagged here when I call the listener as such (where mRequestedScore is different to 0):

```
mListener.onEnteredScore(mRequestedScore);
```

The first activity's class implements the second activity listener like this:

```
public class FirstActivity extends BaseGameActivity 
                           implements SecondActivity.Listener
```

And includes the onEnteredScore method as such

```
@Override
public void onEnteredScore(int requestedScore) {

checkForAchievements(requestedScore);
    pushAccomplishments();  
}
```

I am not entirely sure if the error appears because the listener is expecting a click or some action by the user, or the "linkage" is not being established properly between both activities.

I looked around for similar issues but haven't found anything yet.

Apologies if the mistake is obvious.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: `mListener` is `null`. There is no mystery here.

Comment: what am I supposed to initialised it to so that it refers back to the first activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "linkage" isn't established, hence the `null`.

If you want to pass data between Activities (not fragments), you'll need to use the Intent framework - see [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)

The Interface method that you are following in the Type a Number Challenge is useful for passing data between Fragments and the parent Activity. That is what it is being used for in that example. You don't appear to be using Fragments.

For achievements, you are probably better served using a class attached to your `FirstActivity`. That class can then implement your `Listener` interface (if the interface is even useful at that point). Using a separate activity is far more heavyweight than is required.